# General Results for Complicated Constraint Satisfaction Problem

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, co.combinatorics, graph-colouring, csp

Consider the following problem: on a finite two-dimensional grid (say the grid points are vertices of a graph), I need to color the vertices in such a way to satisfy the existence and nonexistence of certain coloring configurations. The color configurations take forms like: there exists a vertex with color $a$ so that all vertices in the row of that vertex have colors in the set $\{a,b,c\}$ and all vertices in the column have colors in the set $\{c,d\}$; or they could be something like: there does not exist a column of vertices all with color $b$.

The number of dimensions in my problems is always fixed (e.g., 2-dimensional grid, 3-dimensional cube, and so forth) and the number of colors is fixed, but the constraints can change and I can vary the size of "graphs" I use. Given a problem, I need to determine whether there exists a colored graph (which will look like a hypercube in general) so that the existence and nonexistence constraints (coloring configurations) are satisfied.

I need to make general claims about problems of this kind (e.g., a graph always exists to solve problems with coloring configurations of a specific form; or, such a graph never exists for coloring configurations of a certain form, etc...). It would also be nice to know some properties about the graphs I need (e.g., the maximum size of the smallest graph that solves a particular class of such problems; or properties about the color patterns in such a graph, etc...).

Are problems of this type studied anywhere? Best I can tell right now, they are just complicated constraint satisfaction problems, but I can't find what I need out there. I need to read more about the mathematics behind these problems. I am most interested in understanding the general properties of such problems, and not so much in algorithms (though I don't mind learning about algorithms). Any references would help. References to subjects I need to read about, theorems, articles, and so forth would be great.

Comment: one angle is empirical study via SAT. it appears all your cases/ examples can be reduced to SAT. 2d grids of constraints show up in physics [Ising model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) which is known to connect to NP complete problems but there the constraints are generally local. also though maybe your formulation is a bit too broad to fit into specific problems.

Comment: Do you have more explicit restrictions on the kinds of constraints you seek?  Depending on the form of these constraints, this might be just an ordinary CSP (existential conjunctive sentences over a first order logic with relation symbols), a list-colouring problem, or something requiring a larger fragment of FOL or MSO.